# set mutations in python, why is the below code not giving me desired result

Tags: python

I am just trying to implement set mutations, following is the code of the same

```
a=raw_input()
setA=set(list(map(int,raw_input().split())))
N=int(raw_input())
for i in range(N):
    operation=raw_input().split()
    setB=set(list(map(int,raw_input().split())))
    if 'update' in operation[0]:
        setA.update(setB)
    elif 'intersection_update' in operation[0]:
        setA.intersection_update(setB)
    elif 'symmetric_difference_update' in operation[0]:
        setA.symmetric_difference_update(setB)
    elif 'difference_update' in operation[0]:
        setA.difference_update(setB)
print sum(setA)
```

if i implement the above code ,what i notice is no instructions other than update is actually implemented... 
Can someone explain me the reason behind it!
inputs= string with space between them
output should be sum of elements present in setA
Thanks for your response in advance :)

Comment: if `update` is not in `operation[0]`, how can `intersection_update`, `symmetric_difference_update` and  `difference_update`  be present in `operation[0]`? So, any of your `elif` will never get executed.

Comment: What are the likely values for `operation[0]`? Why do you test  `'update' in operation[0]` rather than `'update' == operation[0]`?

Comment: thanks @PeterWood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if 'update' in operation[0]:
    setA.update(setB)
elif 'intersection_update' in operation[0]:
    setA.intersection_update(setB)
elif 'symmetric_difference_update' in operation[0]:
    setA.symmetric_difference_update(setB)
elif 'difference_update' in operation[0]:
    setA.difference_update(setB)
```

Closely look at this code snippet. If the substring `update` not in `operation[0]`, there is no chance that `intersection_update` exist in `operation[0]`. Some goes for other elifs.

On the other hand, say your `operation[0]` contains `symmetric_difference_update`, even then the corresponding elif will not get called. Because, then `if 'update' in operation[0]` is also true, and this will get executed. So, even for valid inputs, only the first if will get executed.

**What is the solution then?**

You have to change the order of your conditions. Place the bigger strings on top, and sub-strings of that bigger strings  on bottom so that you  above case is never generated. One of the solutions:

```
if 'symmetric_difference_update' in operation[0]:
    setA.symmetric_difference_update(setB)
elif 'difference_update' in operation[0]:
    setA.difference_update(setB)
elif 'intersection_update' in operation[0]:
    setA.intersection_update(setB)
elif 'update' in operation[0]:
    setA.update(setB)
```

Or, more appropriately, you can just check `==` rather than `in`. Then order doesn't matter.

Comment: @PeterWood, already added that. Thanks BTW.

Comment: understood (y)
thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what input data you are processing but Im guessing that the problem is that you are using

```
needle in haystack
```

which matches part of a string rather than

```
A==B
```

Which matches an exact string. Possibly you will want to strip white space before doing this. So I suggest trying this:

```
a=raw_input()
setA=set(list(map(int,raw_input().split())))
N=int(raw_input())
for i in range(N):
    operation=raw_input().split()
    setB=set(list(map(int,raw_input().split())))
    command = operation[0].strip()
    if 'update' == command:
        setA.update(setB)
    elif 'intersection_update' == command:
        setA.intersection_update(setB)
    elif 'symmetric_difference_update' == command:
        setA.symmetric_difference_update(setB)
    elif 'difference_update' == command:
        setA.difference_update(setB)
print sum(setA)
```

Comment: Lots of speculation, better to clarify first with comments on the original question.